# User.mutual_guilds returning an empty list

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I decided to code another bot, but this time I coded it with an on_message support function. It worked perfectly fine until I decided to let the user choose which Server the problem relates to. So, i passed ctx (basically the message), and used `self.ctx.author.mutual_guilds`. And now, I ran into problems, because mutual_guilds returned an empty string. Can anybody please explain me why this happens?

```py
class ChooseTicketServer(Select):

    def __init__(self, ctx, id):
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.id = id
        self.ServerOptions = [SelectOption(label="Test", value="Test")]
        self.servername = None

        print(self.ctx.author.mutual_guilds)

        for guild in self.ctx.author.mutual_guilds:
            self.ServerOptions.append(SelectOption(label = guild.name, value=f"Server-ID: {guild.id}"))
        
        super().__init__(placeholder="Choose the Server your Problem relates to...", min_values=1, max_values=1, options=self.ServerOptions)
```

```py
class SupportViewCreate(View):
    
    def __init__(self, *, timeout: float = 120.0, ctx, id):
        super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
        self.ctx = ctx
        self.id = id
        self.add_item(ChooseTicketServer(ctx=self.ctx, id=self.id))
```

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if ctx.author == bot.user:
        return
    if not ctx.guild:

        id = random.randint(0, 99999999999999999999)

        while id in bot.activeSupportIDs:
            id = random.randint(0, 99999999999999999999)
        
        bot.activeSupportIDs.append(id)

        embed = Embed(title="Support Ticket", description="Please choose the Server your Problem relates to.", color=discord.Colour.green())
        embed.set_author(name=f"{ctx.author.display_name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar)
        embed.add_field(name="Ticket-ID: ", value=f"#{id}")
        embed.set_footer(text=f"This is an automatically sent message from {bot.user.name}.")

        View = SupportViewCreate(ctx=ctx, id=id)
        await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed, view=View)
    
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(ctx)
```

Comment: Please paste your code instead of putting them in images. It helps use reproduce your errors with ease

Comment: Did it rn since pictures didn't work. And the problem is: there aren't any errors 

Comment: According to the docs, it only returns a list of mutual guilds based on the cache. The cache may not be fully loaded. Also, make sure you're connected to the bot in multiple guilds

Comment: ok, thank you for your prompt reply!

Comment: And, how do I find out if the cache's fully loaded?

Comment: So, how exactly can I solve this? Just wait? And if so, how long? I've been waiting for 4 mins now and it still doesn't work, and I've got 2 mutual guilds with the bot.

Comment: Interact with the bot in all guilds, it should load into cache

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!